# CMake copy multiple config files into build folder

Tags: cmake

I am trying to copy muiltiple configuration files into the build directory with CMAKE. But for some reason it doesn't work.

I know there is `configure_file` but in my case i have multiple files that i want to copy so i tried to glob them.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE myprog_cfg
    "myprog/config/*"
)

add_custom_command(
    TARGET CMakeSFMLProject
    COMMENT "Copy config"
    VERBATIM
    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
    PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${myprog_cfg}  $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:CMakeSFMLProject>
    VERBATIM
)
```

The comment is printed so i know the command is run, but the config files are not copied to the build directory. There is no error or anything. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

`message(STATUS "myprog_cfg: ${myprog_cfg}")` prints all files in `myprog/config/`.

> myprog_cfg: C:/path/to/project/myprog/config/fonts.cfg;C:/path/to/project/myprog/config/settings.cfg;C:/path/to/project/myprog/config/random_other_config.cfg

Comment: What is content of `myprog_cfg` variable after you fill it with `file(GLOB)`? You may print the variable's value e.g. with `message(STATUS "myprog_cfg: ${myprog_cfg}")`.

Comment: It contains all the absolute file paths to the files in the directory separated by a semicolon. I am running this on windows and the paths contain `/` instead of `\` could that be a problem?

Comment: I rather think the semicolons are the problem. Join the list into a string or iterate over the items.

Comment: How would i do that with cmake?